# convert line to polygon in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop

How do I convert a non-closed line (think of it as a C) to a polygon filling the area in ArcMap?

I think I can convert a ring to a polygon with the *Construct Polygon* function on the *Advanced Editing* Toolbar. However I get the following error: "No polygons were created. Ensure the selected features form continuous rings and overlap the polygons."

Obviously, I need to make my C into an O. It's just a matter of adding a line segment between the two endpoints. How do I add that segment and make the line into a ring?

Comment: How good are you at python, VB.net or C#? You could fumble through it by feature vertices to points (both ends), add XY coordinates, export to a table then points to lines to close the gaps by going directly from start-end (or end-start) but this would be a lot better with code.. if you have some please post it.

Comment: Make it an answer perhaps?

Comment: If my comment has helped you come to an answer feel free to expand with your methods, pictures and links to answer your own question and I'll upvote it.

Comment: Convert line to vertices, points to line (close), result to polygon. Script is a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

A manual solution was suggested by Michael Stimson in a comment to the Q:

- Use *Feature Vertices to Points (Data Management)* to convert the line into a list of points
- Use *Points to Line (Data Management)* and tick *Close Line* to get a ring.
- Activate edit mode by clicking *Editor > Start editing* on the *Editor* toolbar. Select a target layer that supports polygons. This does not have to be the source layer with your ring (line).
- Select the ring and convert it to a polygon with the *Construct Polygon* function on the *Advanced Editing* toolbar.

I accessed the first two functions from the search button which is usually on the right of the screen.